# How to check the existence of the User from the Autocomplete in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autocomplete

i am using rails 2.3.11. I have a text_field_with_autocomplete thing used inside a form of model blog

```
        <% remote_form_for :blog, :url => {:controller => "blogs", :action =>"add_blog"} do |f|%>
              <%= f.text_field :title, :class => "admtxt1 wd1 lfloat" %>

               <%= text_field_with_auto_complete "user_login", :login, { :size => 15}, { :url => {:controller => 'users', :action => 'autocomplete_for_blogowners'}, :method => :get, :param_name => 'term', :indicator => "spinner"} %>

                <%= submit_tag "Save", :class => "btn-small margintop10" %>
        <%end%>
```

In the blogs_controller,add_blog action i have

```
 def add_blog
   unless params[:blog].nil?
       @blog = Blog.new(params[:blog])
        @user = User.find_by_login(params["user_login"][:login])
        @blog.owner = @user
   end

  respond_to do |format|
    if @blog.save
           @saved = true
           format.js { render :action => 'add_blog' }
    else
           @saved = nil
           format.js { render :action => 'add_blog' }
    end
  end
 end
```

In my add_blog.js.rjs file

```
     if @saved.nil?
           page.replace_html 'message','<div id="msg" class = "textcolor3">' + @blog.errors.full_messages.join('<br />') + '</div>'
     else
             page.replace_html 'message','<div id="msg" class = "h3txt textcolor3"> Blog created successfully </div>'
     end
```

My blog tablehas id,title,owner_id

And my model has the validation
  validates_presence_of :owner_id, :title

The above code works perfectly with the validation of owner shouldnt be blank

But it didnt checks for the wrong user

For eg. if i am typing something where such a user doesn't exists .In that case if i am submitting the form with no results found in the box , Even tat time i am getting Owner shouldn't be blank.

How to check the existence of the User in this case and to add that in the error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very strange. Why don't you use Rails 3?
Why don't you use REST and CRUD ? 
Sorry but it is better to rewrite code absolutely.

It seems as php code, have you used php?